# Does a exception with just a raise have any use?

Tags: python, exception

For example, here is some code from django.templates.loader.app_directories.py.[1]

```
try:
    yield safe_join(template_dir, template_name)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    # The template dir name was a bytestring that wasn't valid UTF-8.
    raise
```

If you catch an exception just to re raise it, what purpose does it serve?

[1] http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the code you linked to is another additional exception handler:

```
try:
    yield safe_join(template_dir, template_name)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    # The template dir name was a bytestring that wasn't valid UTF-8.
    raise
except ValueError:
    # The joined path was located outside of template_dir.
    pass
```

Since [`UnicodeDecodeError`](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html?highlight=unicodedecodeerror#exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError) is a subclass of `ValueError`, the second exception handler would cause any `UnicodeDecodeError` to be ignored. It looks like this would not be the intended effect and to avoid it the `UnicodeDecodeError` is processed explicitly by the first handler. So with both handlers together a `ValueError` is only ignored if it's not a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Comment: Thanks. Did not know that  `UnicodeDecodeError is a subclass of ValueError`. That helps.

Answer (score 3):

None at all, that I can think of, except if you're debugging that source code and set a breakpoint on the `raise` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, it's unneeded.

Some possibilities:

1. For documentation purposes - just to make it explicit which exceptions are expected
2. As a placeholder for a future (or past) more serious handling before re-raising

Answer (score 1):

The most common use is to propagate some one particular exception and handle all the rest. You can find a lot of examples for propagating `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit` (e.g. look at `asyncore` source): it's convenient for servers to log and continue in case of error in request handler, but you shouldn't catch `KeyboardInterrupt` to exit on `SIGINT`.