# In Python is there any reason to use try/except if errors are just going to be re-raised?

Tags: python, exception

Is there any best practice, stylistic or programmatic reason to catch StandardErrors if I'm just going to re-raise them?

In other words, is it better for any reason to do this:

```
try:
    do_something()
except StandardError:
    raise
```

Instead of just this:

```
do_something()
```

I see this question [Does a exception with just a raise have any use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774792/does-a-exception-with-just-a-raise-have-any-use) which says that this is often used when some errors are `pass` and others are `raise` which I understand; and it suggests that the former is more useful for documentation (?) and as placeholders for future, which are both human-level reasons.

I'm just wondering if there's any lower-level answer, or even just which would be considered more Pythonic?

Comment: You might want to do *something else* between excepting and re-raising

Answer (score 1):

If you want to log your errors (for example) you can do this:

```
try:
    do_something()
except StandardError as ex:
    print(ex)
    raise
```

And just

```
try:
    do_something()
except StandardError:
    raise
```

explicitly shows that you know about possible exception but don't want to catch it.